# VB6 project using functionality in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a piece of code contained in a function that is duplicated in a VB.NET project and VB6 project.  Long term the VB6 project will be phased out.  However, short term I want the VB6 project to call the VB.NET function.  I see a number of options:

```
1) Add VB.NET reference to VB6 project
2) Expose the VB.NET functionality to the VB6 project via a web service
```

Performance is important.  I am trying to decide the best option.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253875/i-want-to-use-a-vb-net-dll-in-a-vb6-program-is-it-possible

Comment: The Web Service route wouldn't require you to ensure COM compatibility for your .NET assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vb.net to make a COM dll and call it from VB6. Here's an example (older; vs2005):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28591/Creating-a-COM-DLL-with-VS-A-Walkthrough

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have several options:
1) Web Service (performance will be affected because of the serialization or deserialization of parameters)
2) Expose functionality using COM or COM+
3) Or if you need to use a VB.NET UserControl you can use the Forms Interop Toolkit (nice article on code project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18954/%2FArticles%2F18954%2FInterop-Forms-Toolkit-2-0-Tutorial)
4) I have not verified this option but you might be able to also use XAML islands